# Crop rectangle not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I am using the following code to crop: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/95/Upload-and-Crop-Images-with-jQuery-JCrop-and-ASP.NET

The first part works alright. However, before doing the actual crop, I am unable to see the select rectangle.

Here are the script tags:

```
<script src="jquery-1-7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.Jcrop.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jcrop_main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.Jcrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.Jcrop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#imgCrop').Jcrop({
                onSelect: storeCoords
        });
    });

    function storeCoords(c) {
        jQuery('#X').val(c.x);
        jQuery('#Y').val(c.y);
        jQuery('#W').val(c.w);
        jQuery('#H').val(c.h);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C# and DLLs?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Absolutely nothing! :D

Comment: I don't get it. Question title is "when is a .dll loaded" and you show us some javascript ? o.O

Comment: Post-edit readers: The original title was "When is a .dll loaded" and was tagged only as "C#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be loading multiple versions of JQuery itself, and the plugin, which is possibly causing problems.  Does the browser show any javascript errors?

Comment: actually on running the program in IE, this is the error it gave me. Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined. Its pointing to the jcrop_main.js

Comment: @user575219 'jquery-1-7.js' is a version of jQuery, as is 'jquery.min.js'. 'min' files are usually just minified versions of the code - i.e. you only need either the full code, or the minified code, not both.